# Visual Studio 2019 switching color theme multple times after startup

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Every time when I start a new instance of Visual Studio 2019, VS switches from Light to Dark theme multiple times all by itself, within a few seconds, mostly ending in the Light theme. I then have to switch back to the Dark theme, which is what I want. Then it stays with the dark theme.
I have created this dark theme using color theme editor back when I used VS 2017.
I switched off "Synchronize settings across devices when signed into Visual Studio" under "Enviromment/General/Accounts" but that didn't help.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem for months. The CPU goes sky rocket and I get epileptic situation. It also happens when I add a project to a solution. Please help!!!